# Morse code to a normal text doesn't work with Hashmap

Tags: java

I was trying to make an morsecode translater. I already had the sentence to the morse code but now I am trying to do it the other way. But I am stuck here. I make it with some getters and setters where I can give input forn the sentence and for the choose between sentence to morse code and morse code to sentence.

My public static void main where I make put in my sentence and where i check which row in the hashmap i need to make the sentence:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class MorseCodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MorseCode morseCode = new MorseCode();
        morseCode.setType();
        int type = morseCode.getType();
        morseCode.setInput();
        String zin = morseCode.getInput().toLowerCase();
        int i = 0;

        if (type == 1) {
        while (i < zin.length()) {
                HashMap<Character, String> letters = new HashMap<Character, String>();
                letters.put('a', ".-");
                letters.put('b', "-...");
                letters.put('c', "-.-.");
                letters.put('d', "-..");
                letters.put('e', ".");
                letters.put('f', "..-.");
                letters.put('g', "--.");
                letters.put('h', "....");
                letters.put('i', "..");
                letters.put('j', ".---");
                letters.put('k', "-.-");
                letters.put('l', ".-..");
                letters.put('m', "--");
                letters.put('n', "-.");
                letters.put('o', "---");
                letters.put('p', ".--.");
                letters.put('q', "--.-");
                letters.put('r', ".-.");
                letters.put('s', "...");
                letters.put('t', "-");
                letters.put('u', "..-");
                letters.put('v', "...-");
                letters.put('w', ".--");
                letters.put('x', "-..-");
                letters.put('y', "-.--");
                letters.put('z', "--..");
                letters.put(' ', "/");

                System.out.print(letters.get(zin.charAt(i)) + " ");
                i++;
            }

        }
        else {
            while (i < zin.length()) {
                HashMap<String, Character> morse = new HashMap<String, Character>();
                morse.put(".-", 'a');
                morse.put("-...", 'b');
                morse.put("-.-.", 'c');
                morse.put("-..", 'd');
                morse.put(".", 'e');
                morse.put("..-.", 'f');
                morse.put("--.", 'g');
                morse.put("....", 'h');
                morse.put("..", 'i');
                morse.put(".---", 'j');
                morse.put("-.-", 'k');
                morse.put(".-..", 'l');
                morse.put("--", 'm');
                morse.put("-.", 'n');
                morse.put("---", 'o');
                morse.put(".--.", 'p');
                morse.put("--.-", 'q');
                morse.put(".-.", 'r');
                morse.put("...", 's');
                morse.put("-", 't');
                morse.put("..-", 'u');
                morse.put("...-", 'v');
                morse.put(".--", 'w');
                morse.put("-..-", 'x');
                morse.put("-.--", 'y');
                morse.put("--..", 'z');
                morse.put("/", ' ');

                Collection<Character> values = morse.values();

                for (Character Character: values) {
                System.out.print(Character);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

this are my getters and setters:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MorseCode {
    String input;
    int type;

    public MorseCode() {
        this.input = "";
        this.type = 0;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Zin");
        this.input = input.nextLine();
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("morse naar zin in van zin naar morse?");
        this.type = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

the get/setInput function is for the sentence what i want to translate and the type is in which way I want to tanslate it. I hope that someone can help me with solving this problem.

Comment: What is the error that you are facing??

Comment: Hey I've built a morse code translator before, check if it can help you https://github.com/unobatbayar/morse-code-translator

Comment: @Vishwa Ratna I don't get an error but when I put in a String with morse code I get al the letter what have an . or - in the code instead of 1.

Comment: Well, in your else block where you try to handle morse code to string conversation (I think), you don't even do anything with your input String `zin` at all.  You just fill a map and then print all the values of that map in a loop. It honestly looks like you didn''t finish your method and just stopped programming at some point...

Comment: Also: Creating your maps inside the loops is really a waste, as that will mean they will be created an filled over and over again. You really should only be doing this once at the start of your program.

Comment: It's best to put your Morse code map into the `MorseCode` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this code you are just printing out every letter you added to your map:

```
Collection<Character> values = morse.values();

for (Character Character: values) {
  System.out.print(Character);
}
```

Depending on your input you want to split the morse-code and get the value from the map.

For example if your user inputs ".- -.... -.-." you could split the String and get every value and get the value from the map. Instead of the while-loop in the else-block.

```
String[] parts = zin.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String part: parts) {
    sb.append(morse.get(part));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```